# Sorting, finding average, comparing and much more in 2D Object array

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I need to store information, including `string` ,`int` and `double` and to perform some actions with it. So, I made an 2D array `Object arr [][] = new Object [100][5];` The columns are -              `String   String   int(may be double/float)   Double(may be float)   Date` User have to insert all info by his own, so let's imagine we have smth like this:

```
name  author  nr   price   date
yyy    aaa    1    10.0    10.02.2013
zzz    bbb    2    20.0    11.03.2014
xxx    aaa    3    30.0    12.04.2015
```

So, I try to do following things: (I would really appreciate any piece of help to any of those!)

1. User has to insert author name (column 2) and program should give him average price of all goods by this author (from column 4). Here's my code:

   ```
   double count=0;
   double s=0;
   System.out.println("Type author");
   scan.next();
   String auth = scan.nextLine();
   for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
       if(arr[i][1].equals(auth)){
           count++;
           s = s+(double) arr [i][3];
       }
   }
   double average = 0;
   average = s/count;
   System.out.println("Average:" + average);
   ```

   However, it gets `NaN` in result. As far as I understand the problem is that my array is an object, but I need to get numbers. One thing I can think of - is to make additional array of these numbers and then count average in it, but it doesn't sound good.
2. Second problem - I need to do two types of this 2D array sorting - by name (column 1) and price (column 4). Actually, I don't have an idea how to to this and don't know if it is even possible. I have read about 2D column sorting in different topics, but they were about pure string or pure int arrays. Had an idea to divide it to different arrays, but don't know if it worth it. I would appreciate any help in solving this question.
3. And last one - how do I implement date to my array? I mean, is there a way to add it, that it would look like `20.02.2013`, not smth like `Sat Jan 02 00:00:00 GMT 2010`. I could make it a simple string, but I need to have the ability to compare dates later (user inserts date, but program shows all rows after it). Right now I have made date like an ordinary double type number and have comparing code like:

   ```
   System.out.println("Insert date");
       double date1 = scan.nextDouble();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            if (arr[i][4]!=null) {
            if((double)arr[i][4]>date1)
                System.out.println(arr[i][0]);
        }
   }
   ```

   Works fine, but would smth like that work for actual dates?
   Thanks in advance, I will appreciate any help in solving any of those problems. Or maybe my life can be easier, if I change my Object array to something else?

Comment: *So, I made an 2D array* --> That was your first mistake: you should create your own class.

Comment: Yep, this isn't SQL and you're going to have a lot of pointless work to do if you want to access "columns".

Answer (score 0):

You should use a list of rows as data structure. One particular row should be some kind of tuple type (you may want to write a class for this).

Then you can implement selection by iterating over the list of rows and retaining any row matching a specific predicate (use java 8 for this).

Sorting is trivial since you can just use the (row) list's sort method by using some custom Comparator instance.

You can implement column projection by iterating over the list of rows and inserting the values of a column into a special list per column. Then you can do average, sumation, whatever on these lists.

For representing dates you should use the classes provided by the standard library. You may want to use a SimpleDateFormat instance for formatting the date as you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You should really try using objects. Start by making a class to represent your data model:

```
public class Book {
    private String name;
    private String author;
    private int nr;
    private double price;
    private Date date;
    public Book(String name, String author, int nr, double price, Date date) {
        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.nr = nr;
        this.price = price;
        this.date = date;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    // repeat for other getters/ setters.
}
```

Now that you have a class you can start taking advantage of java's built in libraries. Start off by using a `List` to hold your data:

```
List<Book> books = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

The list can be thought of as the outer array, and the fields in each `Book` object can be thought of as the columns. You can now add entries like this:

```
books.add(new Book("yyy", "aaa", 1, 10.0, new Date(10, 02, 2013)));
books.add(new Book("zzz", "bbb", 2, 20.0, new Date(11, 03, 2014)));
books.add(new Book("xxx", "aaa", 3, 30.0, new Date(12, 04, 2015)));
```

---

Lets do some examples:

> User has to insert author name (column 2) and program should give him average price of all goods by this author (from column 4).

```
final String auth = scan.nextLine();
final double average = books.stream()
        .filter(book -> book.getAuthor().equals(auth))
        .mapToDouble(Book::getPrice)
        .average();
```

> I need to do two types of this 2D array sorting - by name (column 1) and price (column 4)

```
books = books.stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Book::getName)
                          .thenComparing(Book::getPrice))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```